# 400 Bad Request during magento 2 REST API Call

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, api, cors, magento2

When using $http.get in angular, I have a problem: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource.....

```
$http({ 
  method: 'GET', 
  url: 'https://<magento_host>/rest/default/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=processing,pending&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=in',
    headers : {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
   }).success(function (data) {

    }).error(function (data) {

    });
```

To avoid cross origin issue, I set below method in .htaccess file in Apache server.

1. Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
2. Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS,
   PUT, DELETE"
3. Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization

In firefox developer tools i get like this

1. Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows
   reading the remote resource at **https:///rest/default/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=processing,pending&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=in. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).**

When i try this rest client debugger tools is worked

> Note : we try to find the solution but we failed. Please help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use below the following code to get the solutions.

Change the options request to 200 ok

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"
</IfModule>
```

finally activate the header and restart the apache

> sudo a2enmod headers
>
> sudo service apache2 restart